# Expected value of e^tx. Moment generating function.

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

This is a question from a Statistics class exam that I still am not sure on how to complete.

The number of accidents in a week follows a discrete random variable X with a probability function 
x|p(x)

0|0.12

1|0.19

2|0.12

3|0.20

4|0.14

5|0.19

6|0.04

calculate $E(e^ {(3x)})$.

We've been working on moment generating functions in class, but each of those take a formula for a single probability like Bin(n,p) or Bern(p), not a table of data. I really need to know step by step how a problem like this works so I can replicate the process for the final with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
E\big(e^{3X}\big) = e^{3\cdot0}P(X=0)+e^{3\cdot1}P(X=1)+e^{3\cdot2}P(X=2)+e^{3\cdot3}P(X=3)+e^{3\cdot4}P(X=4)+e^{3\cdot5}P(X=5)+e^{3\cdot6}P(X=6).
$$

Comment: Do you add up all the individual parts or do you multiply? Because in class today, my professor was describing how you can treat a Bin(n,p) as a Bernoulli by multiplying. How do you know when to add and when to multiply with what information is given to you?

Comment: This is just the definition of expectation for a discrete random variable.  Unless you know some extra information, you cannot assume the distribution is one of the named distributions (such as binomial or Bernoulli)!